# Antiforgerytoken and SPA React with .net framework Web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, csrf, antiforgerytoken

For the past few days I`ve been trying to find a proper solution/documentation explaining how .net framework Antiforgery should be setup for a SinglePage Application without any luck.

I have a .net framework web application with React. The front is a Single page app that communicates with Controllers in backend. The controllers are MVC (not API), but the responses are set to be JSON.

Back in the day, when implementing the Antiforgery, i came across this documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

At the bottom of this documentation there is an example of **Anti-CSRF and AJAX** and it suggest the following:

```html
    <script>
    @functions{
        public string TokenHeaderValue()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
        }
    }

    $.ajax("api/values", {
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {  }, // JSON data goes here
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
        }
    });
   </script>
```

and validation:

```cs
 void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
   {
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";

    IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
    if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
    {
        string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

Notice that when using ***AntiForgery.GetTokens()*** no additional cookies are added to the client. This method generates raw tokens (form and cookie-token). And upon validation, it only validates the rawtokens that are sent via HTTP header (in this case **RequestVerificationToken**)

For my application, since I dont use any Razor, I created a Controller that generates the antiforgery-token explained in the sample above. Once user is logged inn, a request is made to this controller to fetch the token and is used for all the non-safe HTTP requests from client. The validation is the same as the example, here i created an AuthorizeFilter that checks for HTTP header and validates the token.

Everything seem to be working fine. Once user is logged in, the antiforgery is created and upon validation the username is decrypted from authentication-cookie and matched with the one that is encrypted in the antiforgery-token.

What I have noticed is that this antiforgery-token, even though is only meant for a user in particular as it contains encrypted-username, never expires. Meaning that I can log in as user A, grab the antiforgery-token value and log out. Later, when logged in as user A again, I can still use the old antiforgery-token as it still validates just fine.

Maybe I am overthinking this, but wouldn't a CSRF-attack still be possible, if the attacker somehow gets hold of this never-expiring antiforgery-token and sets up an attack specifically for user A?

Again, quite possible I am imagining a hard-core scenario that makes me question if this implementation is at all correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid this is to use SessionID instead of the user name for the token, which will make sure to invalidate your previously copied token.